# my form image is not uploading to server in android java

Tags: java, android

I am trying to upload an image to server in android studio using okhttp in java
the image name is uploading but the image is not uploading to server

I tried the below code

```
void connectServer(File picturePath) throws IOException {


    Request.Builder builder=new Request.Builder();
    RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
           .addFormDataPart("image", picturePath.getName(),RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"),picturePath))
            .addFormDataPart("name",picturePath.getName())
            .build();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()

            .url("url")
            .post(requestBody)
            .build();
    try {


        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().build();
        //client.connectTimeoutMillis(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        Toast.makeText(this, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "poor internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you test server side?

Comment: only name of the image is coming ie. second parameter image is not coming to the server